# share session among different type of web servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, session, autoscaling

Some web services in my company are built with different web apps.(Rails, Django, PHP)

What's the better practice to share the session status

So that user won't have to login again and again among different servers.

I build my Rails apps in AWS auto scaling group.

That is, even I browse the same website, but next time I may browser on another server, so that I have to login again. because the server doesn't have my session status.

I need some better idea or keywords for me to search about that kind of issue.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways in which you can achieve this objective

1. Implement a custom session handling mechanism that makes use of database session management, i.e. all sessions will be stored in a special table in the database and will be accessible to all the servers.
2. Have a Central Authentication Service (CAS) which will act as a proxy to all the other servers. This will then mean that this step has to happen before the requests reach the load balancer.

If you look around, option 1 might be recommended by many, but it **may** also be an overkill since you'll need custom session management in each of the servers. However, your choice would probably depend on the specific objectives you want to achieve, the overall flexibility of the system architecture and the amount of time you have on your hands. The CAS might be a more straightforward way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Storing user sessions in your applications database wouldn't be recommended option for AWS.

The biggest problem with using a database, is that you need to write some clean up script that runs every so often to clear the table of all the expired user sessions. This is messy, creates more overhead, and puts more pressure on your DB.

However, if you do want to use an actual database for this, you should use a NoSQL database like Dynamo. This will give you much better performance than a relational database. It's probably more cost effective too in terms of data transfer. However, the biggest problem with this is that you still need that annoying clean up script. Note There is built in support in the SDK for using PHP with Dynamo for storing the user's session:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-dynamodb-session-handler.html

The best but most costly solution is to use an ElastiCache cluster. You can set a TTL of your choice which means you won't have to worry about clean up scripts. Also ElastiCache will get you much better performance than Dynamo or any relational DB as the data is stored in the RAM of the ElastiCache nodes. The main drawback of ElastiCache is that currently, it can't scale dynamically. So if too many users logged in at once, if you didn't have a big enough cluster already provisioned, things could get ugly.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/WhatIs.html

But you can bet that all the biggest, baddest and best applications being hosted on AWS are either using Dynamo, ElastiCache or a custom NoSQL or Cache cluster solution for storing user sessions.

Note that both of these services are supported in all of the AWS SDKs:

https://aws.amazon.com/tools/